# Python object cannot be interpreted as an index

Tags: python, list, object, typeerror

Running the code below

```
import threading
import io
import Client

Proxies = None
Users = None

with open("proxies.txt") as x:
    Proxies = x.readlines()

with open("ids.txt") as f:
    Users = f.readlines()

c = 0
for udata in Users:
    uid = udata.split(':')[0]
    ok = udata.split(':')[1]
    while True:
        proxy = Proxies[c].strip('\n')
        proxySplit = proxy.split(':')
        c = Client.Client(proxySplit[0], proxySplit[1], uid, ok, 171147281)
        if(c):
            c += 1
            break
```

I've got this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Run.py", line 20, in <module>
proxy = str(Proxies[c]).strip('\n')
TypeError: object cannot be interpreted as an index
```

I can not found what's wrong with my code. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that in line 22 `c = Client.Client(proxySplit[0], proxySplit[1], uid, ok, 171147281)` you make `c` an object, not an `int` anymore. And when it goes to line 20 again, `c` is used as an index, which is not allowed.

Comment: Thank you! I totally missed that out, it's not allowing me to mark it as an answer now, 10 minutes, I will, though, mark it as an answer.

Comment: This is a good part of the reason why style guides tell you to use meaningful names instead of single-letter names for your variables. You're less likely to use the same name for an count and a client object if you call them `count` and `client` instead of trying to pick a single letter for each…

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did. :)